# uiview container - viewwithtag returning null sometimes

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uitextfield

I have a strange problem that occurs sometimes and on random fields.

How i have things set up

UiView - With iad banner and a uiview container which has a table view embeded in it.

[image]

I'm trying to access that fields within the table view. I'd done some research and found that using view with tag was the way to go, so gave all the uitextfields in the table view a tag and then try to access them using

```
UITextField *cReg = (UITextField *)[[self containerView] viewWithTag:1];
```

Which sometimes gets the UITextfield correctly, other times it returns null and i can't work out why

Comment: Please quantify exactly when you see the process fail and when you see it succeed.

Comment: Its totally  random, theres not specific way to get it to succeed or fail. The code is ran when a button is pressed

Comment: This is not the best way to go about accessing cell content. Do you need to access the cell content when the user taps the save button? If so why not use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead?

Comment: yeah, i need to access the text thats been entered in the text fields. i would have accessed them directly but the text fields are defined in a separate file to the save function

Comment: You are operating within a computational environment.  "Totally random" is not possible.  Have you tried setting breakpoints, and using output to console statements to clear up what your objects are encountering?

Comment: @abiessu Randomness is necessarily defined with respect to the observer; all it means is that you don't know the algorithm behind the process, not that one doesn't exist. So, before I know how the traffic lights change, they are random with respect to me. Are they cryptographically random? No. But random nonetheless. Speaking of which, it is possible to get randomness in a computational environment; there's hardware for that, and there are also quite good PRNGs (which are random enough they may as well be true random).

Comment: @ParthianShot: I can agree with that philosophically, but then I would have used the word "unexpected" to describe the program's behavior as it is probably only the case that it *appears* to be random...  (And based on the accepted answer, we now know that it is in fact not random at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might be happening, it's because your `UITextFields` are all inside  `UITableViewCells`, and a UITableViewCell it's only allocated in memory when it's been showing in the screen. So, the hidden cells are not in memory, and their textfields are just nil.

Like Rog said in comments, that's not the best way to access the filds with tableView.

Comment: i could understand that if they all returned null, but some do return the correct text when others don't, both on the same save operation. So whats the best way of going about this considering my current setup, or another way to achieve the same thing

Comment: Do the test. Some of them sould be returning the correct value, its the ones that are been displayed in the screen. The ones that are nil, should be the ones that are hidden in the scroll of the tableView.

Well, if there is someone displayed and still nil, then the problem is really somewhere else

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the problem, if they are all on screen they all are fine, whereas the first one is missing if its been scrolled

Comment: Like I said. You have to find another solution. Your question is now answered, you know why they are nil. If you still need help with finding another way to get the texts, please edit your question or create a new one. Otherwise, just accept this in order to close it.